# SSIS Wrote rows but data is not updated in destination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am writing an SSIS package to import an Excel file to a SQL Server database.I have added 3 data flow tasks each for each sheet in excel and each corresponds to different table in database.
That means one sheet is imported into one table in the database.

The first import works OK, for the second and third I get the error

> Value violated integrity constraints

[image]

Comment: There isn't much point in posting half the error message! Plus, I recommend actually pasting the errors into the question. This enables your question to appear in search results and thus gives you a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Are you loading unique columns to the destination table? if yes, are you deleteing the rows from the destination before reloading them or are you doing incremental load?

Comment: Could you post the error in more detail ? In the image are cut.

Comment: [ShopLocationtable [737]] Error: There was an error with ShopLocationtable.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[SHOPID] on ShopLocationtable.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".

Comment: I think this error is due to entering null values in the not null field.

Comment: Here SHOPID is not null field and in excel after finishing the rows that are filled it is also taking the rows that are empty.so i dont want that empty rows to be taken.so how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, does the task complete the import ? Do you have blank lines after inserting ?